# wp_enqueue_script not working on AJAX called php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I've got a complicated little problem here.

I'm building a WordPress plugin where I select a "parent" post (of a custom type that I made called 'step') and then an AJAX function shows a new select bar with all of the children of that parent. I do this by outputting the new  and  elements in the PHP file that's called in the AJAX function. This works, but now I want to repeat the process to run a function from the same JQuery file when this new outputted  element is added to the page. (See Javascript code)

Main php plugin file (in a folder within the plugin directory):

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: n8jadams Step by Step Plugin (WIP)
Plugin URI:
Description: 
Author: Nathan James Adams
Author URI: http://nathanjamesadams.com
Version: 0.0.1a
*/

//Exit if accessed directly
if(!defined('ABSPATH')) {
    exit;
}

//My custom post type, it works fine
require_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'n8jadams-step-funnel-cpt.php');
require_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'n8jadams-ajax.php');

//Add my javascript
function n8jadams_init_javascript() {
    wp_register_script('n8jadams_javascript', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'n8jadams-scripts.js', array('jquery'),'1.1', false);
    wp_enqueue_script('n8jadams_javascript');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'n8jadams_init_javascript');

//Adds a plugin menu to the wordpress sidebar
function n8jadams_add_plugin_menu() {
    add_menu_page('', 'Steps Settings', 4, 'steps-settings', 'n8jadams_steps_settings', '');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'n8jadams_add_plugin_menu');

//The actual function for the menu page
function n8jadams_steps_settings() {
    //Access the database and the tables we want
    global $wpdb;
    $posts = $wpdb->prefix.'posts';
    //Get the user id
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $userid = $user->ID;

    //Initialize javascript (it works here!)
    n8jadams_init_javascript();

    /* Get all the parents */
    $parentsquery = "
        SELECT `ID`, `post_title`
        FROM $posts
        WHERE `post_author` = $userid
        AND `post_parent` = 0
        AND `post_status` = 'publish'
        AND `post_type` = 'step'
    ";
    $parentsarray = $wpdb->get_results($parentsquery);
    ?>
    <h4>My Forms:</h4>
    <select id="parentselect">
        <option id="-1"> - Select Your Step Form - </option>
        <?php
            //output the parents
            for($i=0;$i<sizeof($parentsarray);$i++) {
                echo '<option id="'.$parentsarray[$i]->ID.'">'.$parentsarray[$i]->post_title.'</option>';
            }
        ?>
    </select>
    <div id="displayChildren"></div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Javascript (n8jadams-scripts.js):

```
(function($){
    $('#parentselect').change(function(s) {
        var thisID = s.target[s.target.selectedIndex].id;
        var outputDisplay = document.getElementById('displayChildren');
        if(thisID != '-1') {        
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'admin-ajax.php',
                data: {
                    action: 'n8jadams_get_children',
                    id: thisID
                },
                success: function(response){
                    if(response == "") {
                        outputDisplay.textContent = "This form has no children. Add them in the sidebar menu of this step form.";
                    } else {
                        outputDisplay.innerHTML = response;
                    }
                },
                error: function(errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });

        } else {
            outputDisplay.textContent = '';
        }
    });

    // I want this function to work
    /*
    $('#childselect').change(function(t) {
        console.log("test");
    });
    */  
})(jQuery);
```

PHP file called by AJAX (n8jadams-ajax.php):

```
<?php
    function n8jadams_get_children() {
        //Get the id of the parent
        $parent_post_id = $_POST['id'];
        //Sanitize the input (Added after question was answered)
        $parent_post_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$parent_post_id);
        //Access database
        global $wpdb;
        $posts = $wpdb->prefix.'posts';
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $userid = $user->ID;
        $childrenquery = "
            SELECT `ID`, `post_title`,`post_content`
            FROM $posts
            WHERE `post_parent` = $parent_post_id
            AND `post_status` = 'publish'
            AND `post_type` = 'step'
            AND `post_author` = $userid
        ";
        //Retrieve the children associated with this parent
        $childrenarray = $wpdb->get_results($childrenquery);

        //Initialize Javascript (it doesn't work here!)
        n8jadams_init_javascript();

        if(!empty($childrenarray)) { ?>
            <h4>My Steps:</h4>
            <select id="childselect">
                <option id="-1"> - Select Your Step - </option>
                <?php
                    //output the children of the parent
                    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($childrenarray);$i++) {
                        echo '<option id="'.$childrenarray[$i]->ID.'">'.$childrenarray[$i]->post_title.'</option>';
        } ?>
            </select>
        <?php wp_die();
        }
    }
    add_action('wp_ajax_n8jadams_get_children', 'n8jadams_get_children');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_n8jadams_get_children', 'n8jadams_get_children');
?>
```

[Screenshot of Plugin Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXus4.jpg)

I cannot figure out why my javascript file isn't working in the PHP file that's called by AJAX. Maybe the vast wisdom of the StackOverflow can help me. Thanks for the help in advance. :)

Comment: You have a sql injection vulnerability in your code. Properly sanitize your variables, or in this case don't craft custom sql queries and use something like WP_Query instead.

Comment: Where is this code supposed to work? The frontend or the backend?

Comment: @Sumurai8 I'll look into security measures against sql injection. I'm not sure about the frontend or backend. I thought that HTML and Javascript are all frontend and PHP is backend. All of the files are located in a directory in the plugins folder. The screenshot shows what the result of the code is in the "Step Settings" sidebar of the WordPress dashboard.

Comment: I meant the frontend or backend of wordpress. Aka what the user normally sees, or wp-admin.

Comment: Any user that's logged in to the Wordpress Dashboard. I guess that means wp-admin? Sorry, kind of new to Wordpress. Thanks for your efforts Samurai8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You are hooking into `wp_enqueue_scripts`, which is only run for the frontend of Wordpress (the part the average visitor sees). If you want to load a script into wp-admin, the backend of Wordpress, use the `admin_enqueue_scripts` action.</s>

Since this code does not work in /wp-admin/, you don't need to use admin_enqueue_scripts. I guess the whole problem would be that you are attaching a handler to `$('#childselect')`, while no such element exists on the page at that time. Use deferring with [`$(..).on(..)`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document).on('change', '#childselect', function(e) {
  //Black magic
});
```

Side note: As already mentioned in the comments, the following part contains an unsanitised variable which will allow an attacker to perform sql injections.

```
$childrenquery = "
    SELECT `ID`, `post_title`,`post_content`
    FROM $posts
    WHERE `post_parent` = $parent_post_id
    AND `post_status` = 'publish'
    AND `post_type` = 'step'
    AND `post_author` = $userid
";
```

Use WP_Query if at all possible. If this is only used from the backend of Wordpress, don't use `wp_ajax_nopriv_*`, because users that are not logged in into your site have no right to use that anyway.

Comment: In the main php file I replaced the line `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'n8jadams_init_javascript');` with `add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'n8jadams_init_javascript');`. Now the ajax function isn't even being called.

Comment: So the url is not `/wp-admin/`?

Comment: I just realized that no matter what I put in for `url` in the javascript file, it works when I use `wp_enqueue_scripts`.The url is `http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=steps-settings`

Comment: Deferring the handler worked! I also added `$parent_post_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$parent_post_id);` to n8jadams-ajax.php to account for SQL injection. Thank you so much!